# Getting git fetch output to file through python

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, subprocess, git-fetch

I am trying to save *git fetch* output to file through python, using:

```
subprocess.check_output(["git", "fetch", "origin", ">>", "C:/bitbucket_backup/backup.log", "2>&1"], cwd='C:/bitbucket_backup/loopx')
```

but I believe there is something missing in *subprocess.check_output* args because when adding *>> C:/bitbucket_backup/backup.log 2>&1* I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 1, in <module>
     subprocess.check_output(["git", "fetch", "origin", ">>", "C://bitbucket_backup//backup.log", "2>&1"], cwd='C://bitbucket_backup//loopx')
  File "C:\Users\fabio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
     **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Users\fabio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 418, in run
     output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['git', 'fetch', 'origin', '>>', 'C://bitbucket_backup//backup.log', '2>&1']' returned non-zero exit status 128.
```

Comment: Don't forward STDOUT/STDERR as the part of the command, that's not how it's meant to be run from Python. `subprocess.check_output` will automatically pipe your STDOUT, and if you're expecting an error use `subprocess.communicate()` instead to capture both streams. You can use `subprocess.Popen()` to fully control the piping, including automatic piping to a file handle if you want to save the output as a file.

Comment: to complete what zwer just said, your command line would need `shell=True` (but that's dirty :))

Comment: It's also not a great idea to depend on `git fetch`'s output: it's not designed for machine parsing. Moreover it behaves differently if stdout is a pipe vs a tty. (There are some flags to try to control this but I ran into a bug trying to use them to show progress in parallel fetching.)

Comment: I know, I had to do some work arounds to be able to depend on git fetch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickfix: enable shell features to handle redirection arguments:

```
subprocess.check_output(["git", "fetch", "origin", ">>", "C:/bitbucket_backup/backup.log", "2>&1"], cwd='C:/bitbucket_backup/loopx', shell=True)
```

But that's really dirty as python is able to do that really nicely:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(["git", "fetch", "origin"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, cwd='C:/bitbucket_backup/loopx')
with open("C:/bitbucket_backup/backup.log","ab") as f:  # append to file
    f.write(output)
```

That said, if you're to rewrite all git commands in python, maybe you should use a git python API like [GitPython](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and also the "better" alternative eheh =P

Comment: also with the "better" alternative I had to do f.write(str(output)) to be able to write in backup.log, but through that it lost line breaks from the default git fetch formatation output.

Comment: check my edit. Just open the file in binary mode. that should do the trick instead of converting to string.